# Card c in video poker

Tags: java

I'm working on a video poker assignment in java. We are given class templates that we are supposed to use in our program. I'm confused as to what `Card c` represents. Like in the method `addCard(Card c)`, does that just mean  it will be executed on the Card object that's currently in use? Here are the class files I've been working on so far. They are far from finished.

Player Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Player {


private ArrayList<Card> hand; // the player's cards
// you will likely need more instance variables

public Player(){        
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList;
}

public void addCard(Card c){
    // add the card c to the player's hand
}

public void removeCard(Card c){
    // remove the card c from the player's hand
}

// you will likely need more methods here
}
```

Deck class:

```
import java.util.Random
public class Deck {

private Card[] theDeck; 
private int top; 
// add more instance variables if needed

public Deck(){
    top = 0
    Card[] theDeck = new Card[52];
    for(int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
    {
    for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.length; i++)
            theDeck[i] = new Card(s,v);
}

public void shuffle()
{
    // shuffle the deck here
    Random generator = new Random();
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp = i;
    int i = generator.nextInt(51) + 1;
    int j = generator.nextInt(51) + 1;
    for(int k = 1; k <100; k++)
    {
        theDeck[i] = theDeck[j];
        theDeck[j] = temp;
    }
    top = 0;
}

public Card deal(){
    // deal the top card in the deck
    if (top < 40)
    {   
        theDeck.shuffle;
    }
    return theDeck[top];
    top++;
}   //this method should add cards to array hand? no addCard will do that.





// add more methods here if needed
//DB getter methods here?

}
```

Card Class:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>{

private int suit; 
private int value; 

public Card(int s, int v){ //constructor of an object Card
    s = suit;
    v = value;
    //make a card with suit s and value v
}

public int compareTo(Card c){
    // use this method to compare cards so they 
    // may be easily sorted

}

public String toString() //to tell the user what card/s they have
{
    myCard.getSuit();
    myCard.getValue();
    if(s == 1)
    {
        if(v == 11)
        {
            return "Jack of Clubs";
        }
        if(v == 12)
        {
            return "Queen of Clubs";
        }
        if(v == 13)
        {
            return "King of Clubs";
        }
        if(v == 1)
        {
            return "Ace of Clubs";
        }
        else{
            return v + " of Clubs";
        }   
    }
    if(s == 2)
    {
        return v + "Diamonds";
    }
    if(s == 3)
    }
        return v + "Hearts";
    }
    if(s == 4)
    }
        return v + "Spades";
    }


//DB method to set 1, 2, 3, and 4 to card suits


//now here create string representation for the Card    
    // use this method to easily print a Card object

public int getSuit()
{
    return s;
}
public int getValue()
{
    return v;
}   

//DB right now have cards in theDeck like Card(2, 10), need Card(d, 10)
//need to convert that to a String d10 
}
// add some more methods here if needed

}
```

Comment: The comment in the method says what it does.

Answer (score 1):

In `public void addCard(Card c)`, `c` is a [parameter](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/lab/javaparm.html).

This means that within the body of the function `addCard`, you can refer to the value passed to the function by the name `c`.  You *call* the function `addCard` with some value (e.g., `theDeck[0]`), and that value will be used in `addCard()`.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I pass the value to the method addCard?

Comment: Also, Card c appears in the compareTo() method in the Card class. Is it there so that I could write something like if(this.value < c.value){ return 1} So c just represents an object within an Array?

Comment: @user3427395 You pass the value by making the call.

Comment: @user3427395 Second question - Yes, that's why it's there.  c represents an instance of a Card.  In this *particular* case, yes, it's an object within an Array.  But you could have a separate Card object that you created somewhere else, and you could call addCard with that Card object as well.